# SwiftUI: How to Save value from a TextField in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am building a very simple SwiftUI App, following a tutorial.
I created a View that contains a list of items which is @fetched from CoreData, and the list is shown with no problem.
Then I added a modal window with a `TextField` and a `Button` to save the data.
This is the code of the modal:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddCategoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    @State public var name: String = ""
    @State public var id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {                
               self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Close")
            }

            Text("Add a new Category")
                .font(.largeTitle)

            TextField("Enter category name", text: $name)
                .padding(.all)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())


            Button(action: {
                let category = Category(context: self.context)
                category.name = self.name
                category.id = self.id
                do {
                    try self.context.save()
                } catch {
                    self.name = "There is an error!"
                }

            }) {
                Text("SAVE \(self.name)")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct AddCategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddCategoryView()
    }
}
```

In this line,

```
Text("SAVE \(self.name)")
```

I am printing (for debugging) the value of the variable name, and I can see that the variables changes to the value that is in the catch statement

```
 self.name = "There is an error!"
```

So I know that the saving is failing. But I have no idea why.

In the List View I have a button that will open this modal; I changed the value of this Button from

```
self.showAddModal.toggle()
```

TO

```
let category = Category(context: self.context)
                category.name = "New Category"
                do {
                    try self.context.save()
                } catch {
                    self.name = "There is an error!"
                }
```

And it works! I can see that the List View is updated with the value. 
This is the code for the List View

```
struct CategoriesView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var categories: FetchedResults<Category>
    @State private var showAddModal = false;
    @State public var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(name)")
            List {
                ForEach(categories, id: \.id) { category in
                    VStack {
                        Text(category.name ?? "Unknown")
                    }
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                let category = Category(context: self.context)
                category.name = "New Category"
                do {
                    try self.context.save()
                } catch {
                    self.name = "There is an error!"
                }

            }) {
                Text("+")
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .cornerRadius(24)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                            radius: 3,
                            x: 3,
                            y: 3)
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showAddModal) {
                AddCategoryView()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CategoriesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return CategoriesView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

I have spent the last 2 hours looking and googling for a solution, but I cannot find out what is wrong in my code. I also tried on the simulator but got the same error; I cannot save the core data from the TextField.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found the solution, which maybe is not the right one but at least it works.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showAddModal) {
                AddCategoryView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
            }
```

Yep, just passing the Environment with the context to the Modal View fixed the issue. I am not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, otherwise you will get a fresh context in your modal view, not the pointer to your main one.